# Why does a floated <span> select together with other neighboring <spans>

Tags: html, css, textselection

I just noticed a weird problem. Suppose you have this HTML:

**case n° 1**:

```html
<span>123</span><span>456</span>
```

This is rendered all together:

```
123456
```

When you double-click this (I'm using Chrome), the entire `123456` gets selected. If you would add a space between them...

**case n° 2**:

```html
<span>123</span> <span>456</span>
```

You get the texts separate

```
123 456
```

And double-clicking selects each of them individually. Now let's remove the space and introduce floats:

**case n° 3**:

```html
<span style="float:right">123</span><span>456</span>
```

This time the texts get rendered separate like this:

```
456                                 123
```

However double-clicking either one still selects BOTH elements - I'm guessing because they are still technically next to each other in HTML. Let's put the space back in:

**case n° 4**:

```html
<span style="float:right">123</span> <span>456</span>
```

The result still looks the same...

```
456                                 123
```

And - SURPRISE - double clicking either of them **still selects both**. What gives?

Interestingly, changing `<span>` to `<div>` fixes the problem. Playing around more, if at least one element has `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` then the strange behavior will be there, and only if both elements have `display: block` will it work right. In addition, this also applies if instead of `float` I use `position: absolute`.

I would like to prevent this weird behavior. Why does it arise and how can I counter it?

Comment: Interesting.. double clicking on the `123` part select only this part.. (case n° 3) FireFox

Comment: cass n°4 doesn't select both on FireFox

Answer (score 3):

Add an `&nbsp;` (or `&#8203;`) instead of a space. This forces the space to render and separate the text into two.

```css
span:first-child
{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<span>123</span>&nbsp;<span>456</span>
```

White space is automatically truncated in HTML, so the regular space is ignored since it <sup>*theoretically*</sup> doesn't affect the flow anymore. You can also force it to render by using the CSS `white-space` property.

```css
span:first-child
{
  float: right;
}

div
{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div><span>123</span> <span>456</span></div>
```

And finally, if you don't want to see that space, set the font size of the container to 0 and the font size of the spans to whatever you want them to be. (You won't need to do this for the zero-width space `&#8203;`)

```css
span:first-child
{
  float: right;
}

div
{
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: 0;
}

span
{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div><span>123</span> <span>456</span></div>
```

Comment: Well, that works... But why? 

Comment: By floating the first span, the browser will essentially "ignore" the white space preceding the second span. Using an `&nbsp;` prevents this. You can see this if you float it to the left instead. Without the `&nbsp;` there is no gap between the two spans. With it, there is.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not ideal because the `&nbsp;` will appear and affect the flow of the non-floated elements.

Comment: For that, you can set the font size of the container to 0 and the font size of the spans to whatever you want them to be.

Comment: I've added both of these as examples in my answer above.

Comment: Hah, I found a better one! The [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) works too, and doesn't need any styling tricks at all.

Comment: Yep that works too.